# my garage has soffit and ridge vents and I want to insulate it (southern NH)

Tags: insulation, garage, soffit

like the thread title says:  I'm located in Southern NH, allegedly we have 4 seasons although I'm having my doubts about the veracity of that (loonnng winter)

I have an attached 2 car garage with a single door.  I wish to insulate it prior to putting up pegboard around the exterior walls.  There is soffit ventilation and a ridge vent.

*Edit* I should mention that the south wall doesn't have a soffit.  The west and east walls do.  The south wall goes up 8' to the header that parallels the trusses.  I plan to put pegboard to the bottom of the header.  Question:  Will the pegboard suffice for ventilation on that wall? */Edit*

Can I use kraft backed fiberglass insulation on the walls and the roof?  Will I need a plastic vapor barrier?  I do not plan to panel the roof. There is no room above the garage.  Could I use lattice to hold the insulation on the roof joists?

thanks in advance for your replies

Comment: Is there a finish ceiling present?

Comment: there is not a finish ceiling present.